# Is this a new lavender plant or a weed or an unknown plant?

Tags: identification, weeds, outdoor, branches, lavender

I have a lavender plant from an old image taken 4 months ago here:
[image: old lavender picture]

Now I notice there is a new plant growth from the mid of the lavender plant. Not sure if it is a lavender or a weed as the root of the new plant seems connected to the root of the lavender plant.

Pardon me of my photo taking skills. Here are some photos for your identification.
[image][image][image]

Is this a new lavender plant growth?
If not, is it a weed?
If not, what plant is it?

Thank you.

Comment: The leaves are so different than lavender leaves I don't see how you could mistake them..
That's a tree, an offspring from the one in the last picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are self set saplings or seedlings of a tree, possibly elder. The lavender is dead and needs to be removed along with the saplings before they get any bigger.

Comment: (Technically not dead, but way overgrown, unpruned and on its way to its demise.)

Comment: Not dead?what are you seeing in the final image that I'm not in regard to resurrectible signs of life?

Comment: Look all the way at the ends of the bare branches.

Comment: Oh, that tiny bit of what might be lavender growth at the bottom of the picture ... last gasp l'd say! It  will never recover and look good, it's done for...

Comment: Yes. I would either pull it now or wait for the last bloom, harvest, then dig it up